# The difference between html onclick attribute and react cnClick attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have an HTML button with onclick attribute and its value is calling a function(say fn).

```js
function fn() {
  document.querySelector("#greeting").innerHTML = "Hello folks";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="fn()">Try it</button>

<p id="greeting"></p>
```

Question: What is the type of onclick attribute? I mean does onclick wants the result of the function call? From the above example, it seems that onclick attribute needs the result of the function call.

**React example**:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState("");

  function fn() {
    setGreeting("Hello Folks");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type={"button"} onClick={fn}>
        Try out
      </button>
      <p> {greeting} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

In the react example, onClick attributes want a function not the result of the function.

> What I have concluded from both the examples is: `onclick` wants the result of the function and `onClick` wants a function.

They are different though it does the same work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes):

> Event handler content attributes, when specified, must contain valid JavaScript code which, when parsed, would match the FunctionBody production after automatic semicolon insertion.

From [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.

---

> They are different though it does the same work.

Yes. HTML and JSX are different languages used to construct a DOM.

Comment: I read one thing about [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-is-an-expression-too). "After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript function calls and evaluate to JavaScript objects." If we take the above example then what does the above statement mean?

Comment: The JSX gets replaced by function calls and literals.

Answer (score 1):

React is not using `HTML` directly, the syntax is similar but it's something else and yes it is **HTML***ish*.

> This funny tag syntax is neither a string nor HTML.

says [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

You don't get to write HTML inside javascript, you just utilize HTMLish type of syntax and write in react. And even though you use javascript, the flow of the react is a lot different than that of a normal web HTML/JS application (in terms of writing).